# Populate array of ImageView with Picasso

Tags: android, arrays, image, picasso

I'm trying to populate an array of ImageViews with Picasso. I get return working URL's from my backend. But when I've applied the URL's to the array of url's used by Picasso to load into the array of ImageViews nothing happens.

I can't find where I might've gone wrong?

```
public class MemoriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,image7,image8,image9,image10,image11,image12;

private String image1_url,image2_url,image3_url,image4_url,image5_url,image6_url,image7_url,image8_url,image9_url,
        image10_url,image11_url,image12_url;


private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

public ImageView[] images;


public String[] urlList = new String[12];
public static final String KEY_URL = "urls";

public boolean image1_exists,image2_exists,image3_exists,image4_exists,image5_exists,image6_exists,image7_exists,
        image8_exists,image9_exists,image10_exists,image11_exists,image12_exists;

public boolean[] existingArray = new boolean[]{image1_exists,image2_exists,image3_exists,image4_exists,image5_exists,
        image6_exists,image7_exists, image8_exists,image9_exists,image10_exists,image11_exists,image12_exists};

public UserFileMapping fileMapping;

public BackendlessUser user = Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        urlList = savedInstanceState.getStringArray(KEY_URL);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_memories);

    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
    image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image4);
    image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image5);
    image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image6);
    image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image7);
    image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image8);
    image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image9);
    image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image10);
    image11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image11);
    image12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image12);

    images = new ImageView[] { image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, image11, image12 };





    downloadAndAttachImages();
}



@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArray(KEY_URL,urlList);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.log_in_menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase){
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void downloadAndAttachImages(){

        Backendless.Data.of(UserFileMapping.class).find(new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<UserFileMapping>>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<UserFileMapping> response) {
                Iterator<UserFileMapping> iterator = response.getCurrentPage().iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    UserFileMapping fileMapping = iterator.next();

                    if(LocalPreferences.isPreferences1(MemoriesActivity.this)){

                        urlList[0] = fileMapping.url_1;
                        urlList[1] = fileMapping.url_2;
                        urlList[2] = fileMapping.url_3;
                        urlList[3] = fileMapping.url_4;
                        urlList[4] = fileMapping.url_5;
                        urlList[5] = fileMapping.url_6;
                        urlList[6] = fileMapping.url_7;
                        urlList[7] = fileMapping.url_8;
                        urlList[8] = fileMapping.url_9;
                        urlList[9] = fileMapping.url_10;
                        urlList[10] = fileMapping.url_11;
                        urlList[11] = fileMapping.url_12;


                    }

                    int size = urlList.length;
                    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
                        Picasso.with(MemoriesActivity.this).load(urlList[i])
                                .into(images[i]);
                    }


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                System.out.println("FAULT:" + fault.getCode());
            }
        });

}
```

}

Comment: Efficient way is to go for a RecyclerView with a grid/ vertical layout, if all the images are of high size, this may cause irresponsive behavior even if this work properly :/

Comment: Have you tried using `getApplicationContext()`? at `Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(urlList[i]).into(images[i]);`

Comment: @KishorPawar Yes I've tried, it makes no difference.

Comment: You can also try `this` only, as your function is in same activity.

Comment: @Knut Did u try to Log the contents of `urlList`? Does it have all the urls?

Comment: @KNeerajLal yes, it doesn't have ALL the url's, but it got the ones that should exist. And I checked their validity.

Comment: @Knut Perhaps you can do something like `if(urlList[i] != null){ Picasso.... }` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: have you checked that your images[i] are null or not?

Comment: @Knut Made any progess?

Comment: @KNeerajLal I got nowhere on this. Instead I created a helper class for the ImageViews and started customizing it for my needs, it turned out well I think. Should I post the solution still you think?

Comment: @Knut Yes please do. Lets close the thread.